# using biblatex-chicago in TexStudio (TexLive)

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, compiling, biblatex-chicago

I am writing my master theses with TexStudio from the TexLive distribution and I would reeally like to use the `biblatex-chicago` citation style. But somehow (and I cannot explain myself why) it does not work. I have the following problem:

Following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate,
backend=biber,
labeldate=false,
eprint=false,
isbn=false,
sorting=nyt,
arxiv=false,
ibidtracker=false,
doi=false,
url=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{C:/Users/Tamara/Desktop/masterthesis/library.bib}

\begin{document}
    sdsdsd \cite{Pager2008}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I am using biber 2.6 and `biblatex` 3.7 and biblatex-chicago 1.0rc1 2016-06-07.

however, I get several warnings and TexStudio (as well as Texworks) don't recognize the command `\addbibresource`.

This it what it says in the logfile

```
% $Id: chicago-dates-common.cbx,v 0.9.1.21 2016/06/07 09:00:02 dfussner Exp $
% This is a biblatex citation style file, adapted from Lehman's
% authoryear-comp.cbx.  It is heavily modified, and contains the
% common code for providing inline citations (and a reference list)
% for the two author-date styles of the Chicago Manual of Style, 16th
% edition.

\ProvidesFile{chicago-dates-common.cbx}[2016/06/07 v 3.4 biblatex
citation style]
```

here, Texstudio seems to think I am using older versions of biblatex? But this is not true??!

I get several warnings (name is depreciated in sorting options please use field), but it seems to work. Are the warnings problematic? Am I using the options wrong???

I don't get errors just warnings:

1. `labeldate option used to determine whether to provide label date fields and biblatex extrayear is renamed to 'labeldateparts', setting this instead. This option is now used to set the format of the labeldate.` 
   ---> do I need to define a labeldate option?
2. `name' is deprecated in sorting specifications, please use '\field'`.
3. `list is deprecated in sorting specifications, please use '\field'`.

This is how my bibtex file looks like as an example. I automatically generated it from Mendeley:

```
@article{Fleischmann2010,
abstract = {This article presents a multilevel analysis of 1363 male and female first- and second-generation immigrants' unemployment rates. In addition to individual characteristics, the effects of macro-characteristics of 13 destination countries in the EU and of more than 100 origin countries of the immigrants are analysed. Immigrants are found to be more often unemployed in countries where natives have higher unemployment rates. Immigrants' unemployment rates are lower in countries with a larger segment of low-status jobs, with higher immigration rates and with a higher GDP per capita. Destination countries' integration policies and welfare state regimes do not affect the unemployment risk of immigrants. At the level of origin countries, immigrants from more politically stable and free, more developed and more wealthy societies are found to be less often unemployed. Immigrants coming from Islamic countries have higher rates of unemployment, while those originating from Western Europe are less likely to be unemployed.},
author = {Fleischmann, Fenella and Dronkers, Jaap},
doi = {10.1177/0950017010362153},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Tamara/Desktop/Masterarbeit{\_}Literatur/Fleischmann Unemployment{\_}among.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {0950-0170},
issn = {0950-0170},
journal = {Work, Employment {\&} Society},
number = {2},
pages = {337--354},
title = {{Unemployment among immigrants in European labour markets: an analysis of origin and destination effects}},
volume = {24},
year = {2010}
}
```

I read in another post that the problem may be that the new udated version of biblatex-chicago uses commands from older versions or something like that? I don't really understand what the problem here is...
I also cannot use commands like "autocite"...

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Perhaps you have two copies of `biblatex-chicago` on your system.  Which one does the `.log` file point to?  Otherwise, please post a minimal document with the actual code that you are trying.

Comment: Works fine for me. But `authordatebackend ` sounds as if a comma is missing somewhere. Your system is not up-to-date, at least biblatex and biber are a lot older than mine. You should run the update manager in admin **and** user mode to check if there are updates.

Comment: I suspect that you encounter some version incompatibilities with your `biblatex-chicago` and `biblatex`. Make an update of all packages involved with 'MikTeX Update' in both admin and user mode (run both tools twice to be absolutely sure).

Comment: hey, thanks for all your advice...however nothing worked :-( I even uninstalled MikTex, and intalled Texlive now....but still, I can't use biblatex-chicago (\addbibresource and \printbibliography still don't work) but they are updated now (biber=2.6  and biblatex=3.7)...any idea what else could be the problem???

Comment: Please add the error messages from the log file.

Comment: Mhhh, your Biber and `biblatex` versions don't match. It should be `biblatex` 3.7 with Biber 2.7. You should also make sure that `biblatex-chicago` is on version `1.0rc1 2016-06-07` (I know you said that you use that version in your question, but since you moved from MikTeX to TeX live, we can't be sure). Use `tlmgr` to update the packages involved. Please update your question with the new information about package versions and warnings/errors.